# Why addEventListener keeps running inside of React useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React beginner here. Below is a simple code snippet which prints the window size whenever user resizing the browser window.

Why the event listener and handleResize() inside the useEffect gets executed on each re-rendering, but NOT the useEffect() function itself?

My understanding is that if one explicitly declares no dependencies, the useEffect should only run once,  hence **anything inside of useEffect** would run only once, too.

Could anyone pls help to demystify this? thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const [winSize, setWinSize] = useState(window.innerWidth);

    const handleResize = () => {
        setWinSize(window.innerWidth);
    };

    console.log('render');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('run useEffect');
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>{winSize}</div>
        </>
    );
}
```

[Here is a gif of the actual rendering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU7qX.gif)

Comment: Because you are attaching an event listener to the `window` object. No need to run `useEffect` more than once, the event listener keeps "running" in the background while the component is mounted and it gets removed on component unmount.

Comment: Thanks Ivanatias! in this case would you say that useEffect is useless? I removed the useEffect and only keeps     window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize), it still works

Comment: i mean, you're probably adding another event handler with each render now. that's not good. It'll work for a little while,

Comment: No, the `useEffect` is not useless. In fact, for this case, this is the correct way to attach an event listener to `window`. You don't want to attach a new event listener every time the component re-renders.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks Ivanatias and Kevin! To summarize the learning - the event listener only attaches once due to the use of useEffect, which is the correct way to do so. The handleResize() keeps getting executed in the background has nothing to do with useEffect, it was because the event listener was monitoring the resize.

Answer (score 0):

`window.addEventListener(...)` is called within `useEffect`, so it gets called once. `handleResize` is not called within `useEffect`, it is called by the browser when the event fires, hence why it can be called multiple times. If you want `handleResize` to run only once, then remove the event listener after the first call.

```js
  const handleResize = () => {
    setWinSize(window.innerWidth);
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for clarifying! now I understand handelResize() was called each time the event fires, which has nothing to do with useEffect.